# Drag and Drop a card using the DragDrop method

Tags: c#

Below is my code for trying to drag a card from a picture box to a panel but it does not work. Can anyone please help me out. When you click on the card and try to move it the cursor changes(like when you select text and move it) but the card doesnt move and it doesnt display when you drop it on the panel.

```
private void Card_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
      Card.Card source = (Card.Card)(sender);
      DoDragDrop(source,DragDropEffects.Move);
}
private void panel1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Card.Card)))
        {

            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
}
private void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
            Card.Card dragCard = (Card.Card)sender;
            dragCard = (Card.Card)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Card.Card));

}
```

Comment: What's your specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your code only contains changes to the mouse pointer. When the card is dropped, you only get the card and then do nothing with it in your code - that's why nothing is happening.

Comment: In other words, the drag and drop mechanism in .Net _only_ contains enough of the drag/drop metaphor to indicate that that is what the user wanted. _You_ have to do everything else, including painting a card, moving it with the mouse as it moves, removing it from the old location, and drawing it at the new location (after drop).